# C++ undefined reference to class that uses template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

I'm pretty new with templates, so please don't be harsh on me if my code is very wrong :)
This is the header file for a class `Key` that uses a template:

```
//Key.h
#ifndef KEY_H
#define KEY_H

#include "../Constants.h"

template<class KeyType>

class Key
{
    public:
        Key<KeyType>(KeyType initial);          
        KeyType increment();

    private:
        KeyType current;

};

#endif /* KEY_H */
```

This is the .cpp file of `Key` class:

```
//Key.cpp
#include "Key.h"

template<class KeyType> Key<KeyType>::Key(KeyType p_initial)
{
    this->current = p_initial;
}

template<class KeyType> KeyType Key<KeyType>::increment()
{
    this->current ++; //KeyType should implement this operator
}
```

So what's the problem? I try to create an instance of `Key` somewhere else in my code, like this:

> Key songID (0); // ERROR: undefined reference to `Key<int>::Key(int)`

and then use

> songID.increment(); // ERROR: undefined reference to `Key<int>::increment()`

Comment: First of all, you have to put generic template definitions in the same file as the declarations ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648900/c-templates-undefined-reference?rq=1)). Secondly, you probably don't want the `<KeyType>` part in `Key<KeyType>(KeyType initial);`, or any of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

- Remove `<KeyType>` from `Key<KeyType>(KeyType initial);` you don't need it.
- And, move class implementation from `.cpp` file to `.h`  file. Thie article is useful: [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html)